# AADSTS50034: To sign into this application the account must be added to the .. directory

Tags: azure, openid, office365

Greets. I am attempting to authenticating users in Azure AD using OpenID auth. All user accounts in Azure AD are sourced from Microsoft Azure Active Directory. Authentication works fine off a test Azure account, however, when authenticating off a particular customer's Azure service, the following error is outputted:

> com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationException:
>   {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50034: To sign
>   into this application the account must be added to the
>   d0698a91-23ba-4495-abdb-5864793c48dc directory.\r\nTrace ID:
>   ed060649-da1d-48d3-b198-1e05e2a05f0d\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   7c2a1d1e-924e-4939-bad5-fe9f3fcac43e\r\nTimestamp: 2015-09-21
>   11:08:18Z"}

I triple checked all settings and they appear correct. Client ID, Client Secret, Tenant Name, Authorization End Point URL and Authentication Callback URL are all correct. The application is added to the the customer's AD directory server. I'm not entirely sure what Microsoft's means by this error? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake. I had the authorization URL hardcoded in the code that retrieved the access Token.

Comment: Hi @jamie, I am having same error, I am using OAUTH 2.0 AUTHORIZATION ENDPOINT url as AUTHORITY.                             ` private String getAccessToken(String resourceId, String clientId,
                                  String username, String password) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return  authenticationContext.acquireToken(
          resourceId,
                clientId,
                username,
                password,
                null
        ).get().getAccessToken();
    } ` Can you please suggest, how did you fix this error

Comment: Yes, Jamie please help community with your detailed answer with the required settings.